# getting error on insertion in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have created a table in mysql named as student with 2 columns named as "S-id int not null auto_increment 14012040" and "S-name varchar(45) not null unique" "primary key(S-id)"....
the table was successfully created..but after inserting one record into db ,on the next insertion it shows error like "dupliction of primary key is not allowed"...plz hlp me whta should i do..
in th below i am posting the screen shots....

[creating table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePbha.png).

[1st insertion successfully addesd][2]

[getting error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E10DA.png)

Comment: will, missing property autoincrement in your definition of table, of first print

Comment: You should include the examples as text in the posting rather than external images.

Answer (score 1):

Your primary key S-id has a default value (14012040).
You only inserts values for S-name and studentcol columns therefore it will use the S-ids default value again and again.
When it runs first it can use the default value because it is not exists in the table. But second time it will throw an error.
You should use auto increment for S-id as *Álvaro Touzón* said.

**UPDATE:**

According to your comment, here is the working create script:

```
CREATE TABLE student (
    S_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    ,S_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL
    ,PRIMARY KEY (S_id)
    ,UNIQUE INDEX S_name_UNIQUE(S_name ASC)
    ) AUTO_INCREMENT=14012040;
```

Working [SQL fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7450a4/1/0).

Comment: Sir....i have selected auto increament for S-id....but it is not working and throwing error...... What changes should i made....can unplz post thm

Comment: CREATE TABLE `bank`.`student` (
  `S-id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT DEFAULT 14012040,
  `S-name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`S-id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `S-name_UNIQUE` (`S-name` ASC));

Comment: HERE IS the code for creating table of student...plz help me to correct this one

Comment: Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Executing:
CREATE TABLE `bank`.`student` (
  `S-id` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 14012040 AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `S-name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`S-id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `S-name_UNIQUE` (`S-name` ASC));

ERROR 1067: Invalid default value for 'S-id'
SQL Statement:
CREATE TABLE `bank`.`student` (
  `S-id` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 14012040 AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `S-name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`S-id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `S-name_UNIQUE` (`S-name` ASC))


here is the error

Comment: Sir.....according ur code ...i will nt get the o/p what i want....i mean i want s-id values like 1401204001,1401204002,1401204003....14012040100.....like this where 14012040 must be auto increment gradually

Comment: Hello, I've updated my answer. It will start the incrementing from 14012040.

Comment: thank you sir for your help... but will you explain me...how this code worked ??